# Weird setState usage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

From React [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html), I got confused by following use of setState.
See this

```
 handleCelsiusChange(temperature) {
    this.setState({scale: 'c', temperature}); // no key
  }
```

Where state is defined like

```
this.state = {temperature: '', scale: 'c'};
```

So instead of what I showed in the beginning I was expecting a call like this:

```
 handleCelsiusChange(temperature) {
    this.setState({scale: 'c', temperature: temperature}); // with key
 }
```

What did I miss?
(Apparently there is some automatic conversion taking place).

PS. `temperature` is just string not an object which you get from child component, e.g.

```
 handleChange(e) {
    this.props.onTemperatureChange(e.target.value);
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just syntactic sugar.

```
{scale: 'c', temperature} // key -> "temperature", value -> temperature
```

is shorthand for

```
{scale: 'c', temperature: temperature} // key and value explicitly defined
```

This can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) (New notations in ECMAScript 2015).

Comment: I thought so so when there is directly value say {myProp}, it gets translated to {myProp: myProp}? (btw. could not find docs about it :))

Comment: I've included a link to the relevant documentation.

Answer (score 4):

With es6, you can define an object property by variable like in the first example (Shorthand property names).

So `temperature` in your first example will be the key, and the value the variable is holding will be the, well, value.

More info [on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

```
var a = 'foo', b = 42, c = {};
var o = {a, b, c};
console.log(o.a) // foo
```

Answer (score 4):

What you are seeing is a feature of ES6, called Object Literal Shorthand.

https://www.eventbrite.com/engineering/learning-es6-enhanced-object-literals/

What you wrote is also 100% correct:

```
  this.setState({scale: 'c', temperature: temperature}); // with key
```

This will only work if the key and value are named the same thing example:

```
this.setState({name, color}); Will equal
this.setState({name:name, color:color});
```

Comment: ah, thanks so this is an ES6 thing.